# Find a sequence and remove previous entries

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series

i have a question regarding the optimization of my code.

```
Signal = pd.Series([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

I have a pandas series containing periodic bitcode. My aim is remove all entries that start before a certain sequence e.g. `1,1,0,0`. So in my example I would expect a reduced series like that:

```
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

I already have a solution for  1, 1 but its not very elegant and not that easily modified for my example: `1,1,0,0`.

```
    i = 0
    bool = True
    while bool:
        a = Signal.iloc[i]
        b = Signal.iloc[i + 1]
        if a == 1 and b == 1:
            bool = False
        else:
            i = i + 1

   Signal = Signal[i:]
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could take a rolling window view of the series with [`view_as_windows`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows), check for equality with the sequence and find the first occurrence with [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

seq = [1, 1, 0, 0]
m = (view_as_windows(Signal.values, len(seq))==seq).all(1)
Signal[m.argmax():]

3     1
4     1
5     0
6     0
7     1
8     1
9     0
10    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for regex - use a [web interface](https://regex101.com/) to identify the pattern.

for example:

```
1,1,0,0,(.*\d)
```

would result in a group(1) output, that consists of all digits after the 1,1,0,0 pattern.